# drupal commerce: issue with add to cart form and translated products

Tags: 7, forms, commerce, i18n-l10n, taxonomy-terms

Hello I have some transtaled products with some attributes, those attributes are also taxonomy terms translated, I have a language switcher.

The "add to cart form" on the product display do not works correctly when I switch the language.

The original language of the products is spanish those products have translation to english

When I visit the product display in spanish (the original language of the products) the "add to cart form" works correctly, I can select between the different product attributes

But when I visit the product display in English then the "add to cart form" show the attributes select empty so I cannot select between the different attributes because they are not showed in the select list of the add to cart form.

This image works ok because I visit the product display in spanish (the original language of the products)
[image]

This image is when I visit the product display in english, please see the color attribute select, it is just empty, and Im sure that the translations are ok.
[image]

Any clue? why is happening this? I cannot find any related issue about this in the commerce issue queue

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, I lose the translations when I select any other attribute option. It's like if the AJAX call was not language aware.
Have you found a solution to your problem?